# median c# wrong calculate

Tags: c#, winforms, median

I have problem with the calculation of the median when I put 1,2, 3 my median is = 44 i don't know why

```
double wynik = 0;
string x1 = textBox1.Text;
string[] tab = x1.Split(',');
int n = tab.Length;

Array.Sort(tab);

if (n % 2 == 0)
{
    double c = x1[(n / 2) -1];
    double v = x1[(n / 2)];
    wynik = (c + v) / 2;
}
else
    wynik = x1[n / 2];

        textBox2.Text = wynik.ToString();
```

Comment: You're calculating using character codes, not numbers - that's why. Try  parsing them using `int.Parse()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are calculating with characters instead of number.
So let's say your `textBox1.Text` is `"1,2,3"`. Then `x1[(n/2)-1]` would point at the *character* `'1'`, which has the `double` value of `48` or something.

You need to parse the strings into int using `int.Parse`:

```
int[] tab = x1.Split(',').Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();
```

And then *use* these values instead the string again:

```
if (n % 2 == 0)
{
    double c = tab[(n / 2) -1]; // tab instead of x1!
    double v = tab[(n / 2)]; // tab instead of x1!
    wynik = (c + v) / 2;
}
else
    wynik = tab[n / 2]; // tab instead of x1
```

Answer (score 7):

That is because `44` is the ASCII value of `,`. And in your `string`, using your current method now, the median is the comma character `,` value = `44`

To get the median, consider of splitting the string by `,` and then **convert each value to numeric data** (like `int`) and then sort it and simply get the middle value among the sorted data..

```
double wynik = 0;
string x1 = textBox1.Text;
int[] tab = x1.Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray(); //this is the trick
int n = tab.Length;    
Array.Sort(tab);
int median = tab[n/2]; //here is your median
```

Answer (score 0):

static void Main(string[] args)
        {

```
        Console.WriteLine("Define Array Size");
        int size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        float reference = 0;
        int[] newArray = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < newArray.Length; i++)
        {
            newArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            reference = reference + newArray[i];
        }
        float Median = reference / newArray.Length;
        Console.WriteLine("The Median is ="+Median);
    }
```

Comment: Just posting a code snippet is not very appreciated here. Could you please give some context, *how* and *why* it solves the OPs problem? Please also refer to [answer].